# Has this patent application (8,559,894) been granted?

Tags: patentability, us8559894

Has this patent [8,559,894](https://www.google.com/patents/US8559894) been granted?

United States Patent  8,559,894 
 Walker    October 15, 2013

Klystron transmitter

Abstract

A Klystron transmitter for use in weather radar systems has a transmitter module for operating with any of various Klystron tubes designed for different frequency ranges, such as a low S-Band range, a high S-Band range, and a C-Band range. Each of the Klystron tubes is designed to have similar operating characteristics, such as output power and operating voltages. In addition, the transmitter module has driver circuitry for driving the Klystron tube of the transmitter, and such driver circuitry is operable over a wide frequency range so that the same driver circuitry can be used for any of the contemplated bands. Accordingly, the same core transmitter circuitry can be used for any of the Klystron tubes allowing a manufacturer to control which of the contemplated bands is implemented by selecting the appropriate Klystron tube and stable local oscillator (STALO) for the desired band. By using the same core design of the transmitter circuitry for all of the Klystron tubes, the overall manufacturing and implementation costs of Klystron transmitters can be significantly reduced.

Inventors:
Walker; William H. (Madison, AL)

Madison, AL   US

Assignee:
Baron Services, Inc. (Huntsville, AL)

Family ID: 
47752023

Appl. No.: 
13/223,942

Filed: 
September 1, 2011

Prior Publication Data

Publication Date

US 20130055552 A1 Mar 7, 2013

Answer (score 1):

**Yes**, probably a bit confusing with all the numbers and dates, but the patent application was filed on September 1, 2011, was assigned Application No.13/223,942, was published as US Pub. No. 2013/005552 on March 7, 2013 and issued on October 15, 2013 as US Patent No. 8,559,894.